# ios Images gallery animation

Tags: ios, animation, image-gallery

[image]

I want to do something like the ibooks images gallery on the top of this image, it contains images, loop animations and frame effects, any ideas how to do that ?

Comment: Check This Link: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnicklockwood%2FiCarousel&ei=khiSUb7bA8nUrQfLo4CoDQ&usg=AFQjCNEKlHFLyhdbYfdcURVkKGbBCHE-SA&bvm=bv.46471029,d.bmk

Comment: check the coverflow animation in the [tapku library](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary). They have a demo version so you can see whether it's what you want :)

Comment: Try this for CoverFlow animation http://code4app.net/ios/CoverFlow/50a34bdc6803fad569000000

Comment: thx rptwsthi, nice sample !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) was the best coverflow sample I found! Thanks rptwsthi.

Answer (score 1):

iCarousel is great, yet a bit heavy. If you have a lightweight project and don't want to add a whole new class, you can try and make a good use of UIImageView: [how to create image gallery in iOS app using UIImageView](http://cases.azoft.com/creating-image-gallery-ios-apps-uiimageview/)